# XML to CSV ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, nokogiri, export-to-csv

I have multiple XML sample files and I would like to convert them in CSV, but there will be multiple of different attributes/nodes for different XML files therefore I dont want to hard code the different attributes. I would like the output to show column header as the first row, then each of the node/record being display vertically like a traditional column and row spreadsheet. 
Here is one the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sd:root xmlns:wd="urn:com.sample/bsvc" sd:version="v31.0">
  <sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request sd:Add_Only="0">
    <sd:Job_Profile_Data>
      <sd:Job_Code>30000</sd:Job_Code>
      <sd:Effective_Date>1900-01-01</sd:Effective_Date>
      <sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
        <sd:Job_Title>Chief Executive Officer</sd:Job_Title>
      </sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
    </sd:Job_Profile_Data>
  </sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request>
  <sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request sd:Add_Only="0">
    <sd:Job_Profile_Data>
      <sd:Job_Code>30100</sd:Job_Code>
      <sd:Effective_Date>1900-01-01</sd:Effective_Date>
      <sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
        <sd:Job_Title>Administrator Job Profile</sd:Job_Title>
      </sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
    </sd:Job_Profile_Data>
  </sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request>
  <sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request sd:Add_Only="0">
    <sd:Job_Profile_Data>
      <sd:Job_Code>30200</sd:Job_Code>
      <sd:Effective_Date>1900-01-01</sd:Effective_Date>
      <sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
        <sd:Inactive>0</sd:Inactive>
        <sd:Job_Title>Facilities &amp; Grounds Maintenance Attendant</sd:Job_Title>
        <sd:Include_Job_Code_in_Name>0</sd:Include_Job_Code_in_Name>
        <sd:Job_Profile_Private_Title>Maintenance Job Title</sd:Job_Profile_Private_Title>
        <sd:Job_Profile_Summary>Maintain cleanliness of the campus building throughout the day and fulfill special requests as needed.</sd:Job_Profile_Summary>
        <sd:Job_Description>&lt;p>Job Description&lt;b> rich text!&lt;/b>&lt;/p></sd:Job_Description>
        <sd:Additional_Job_Description>&lt;p>&lt;b>&lt;i>&lt;span class="emphasis-2">&lt;u>Additional&lt;/u>&lt;/span>&lt;/i>&lt;/b> Job Description&lt;b> rich text!&lt;/b>&lt;/p></sd:Additional_Job_Description>
        <sd:Work_Shift_Required>0</sd:Work_Shift_Required>
        <sd:Public_Job>1</sd:Public_Job>    
      </sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
    </sd:Job_Profile_Data>
  </sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request>
  <sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request sd:Add_Only="0">
    <sd:Job_Profile_Data>
      <sd:Job_Code>30300</sd:Job_Code>
      <sd:Effective_Date>1900-01-01</sd:Effective_Date>
      <sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
        <sd:Inactive>0</sd:Inactive>
        <sd:Job_Title>Sample_Job_Title</sd:Job_Title>
        <sd:Include_Job_Code_in_Name>0</sd:Include_Job_Code_in_Name>
        <sd:Job_Profile_Summary>Sample Job Profile Summary</sd:Job_Profile_Summary>
        <sd:Job_Description>Sample Job Description</sd:Job_Description>
        <sd:Additional_Job_Description>Sample Additional Job Description</sd:Additional_Job_Description>
        <sd:Work_Shift_Required>1</sd:Work_Shift_Required>
      </sd:Job_Profile_Basic_Data>
    </sd:Job_Profile_Data>
  </sd:Put_Job_Profile_Request>
</sd:root>
```

The code I used but come out incorrectly:

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.read('jobProfile.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(file)
a = []

CSV.open('xmloutput.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << doc.at('.').search('*').map(&:name)
  doc.search('.').each do |x|
    csv << x.search('*').map(&:text)
  end
end
```

Each set of record with its column headers and data being set horizontally. But I would like to iterate the data and keep one row of column headers. I am not sure how to do that without hard coding each of the attributes :/
Please help as I am still new to programming, and I have tried to find solution for a week :(

[screenshot showing the csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXmx6.png)

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. As always, try and break down this big problem into smaller ones so the solutions are simpler.

Comment: I am trying to parse the column header into the first row, and iterate the data from each of the node/record lining down like a traditional excel spreadsheet. As you can see from the screenshot, each of the record : column and data being extracted out from the code horizontally which its not what I am looking for. please advise.

Comment: The CSV works in `csv << row` form, so you may need to create a row incrementally before stuffing it into the `csv`. You should complete the row before adding it, not add bits and pieces as you go.

Comment: It would help if you clarify the expected output - eg what CSV would you expect for this XML sample? I'm guessing that you want each "Put_Job_Profile_Request" to be a row. However, I'm not quite sure what the expect column headings are - specifically those in the "Job_Profile_Basic_Data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first build an array of hashes and extract the keys as headers and then put the values in the right column, all nodes flattened to columns, ignoring the root and record keys.

Something like this

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'set'

file    = File.read('jobProfile.xml')
doc     = Nokogiri::XML(file)
record  = {}
keys    = Set.new
records = []
csv     = ""

doc.traverse do |node| 
  value = node.text.gsub(/\n +/, '')
  if node.name
    if node.name != "text" # skip these nodes
      if value.length > 0 # skip empty nodes
        key = node.name.gsub(/sd:/,'').to_sym
        # if a new and not empty record, add to our records collection
        if key == :Job_Profile_Data && !record.empty?
          records << record
          record = {}
        elsif key[/Job_Profile|^root$|^document$/]
          # neglect these keys
        else
          key = node.name.gsub(/sd:/,'').to_sym
          # in case our value is html instead of text
          record[key] = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(value).text
          # add to our key set only if not allready in the set
          keys << key
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# build our csv
File.open('./xmloutput.csv', 'w') do |file|
  file.puts %Q{"#{keys.to_a.join('","')}"}
  records.each do |record|
    keys.each do |key|
      file.write %Q{"#{record[key]}",}
    end
    file.write "\n"
  end
end
```

Which gives in our csv file the following

```
"Job_Code","Effective_Date","Job_Title","Inactive","Include_Job_Code_in_Name","Job_Description","Additional_Job_Description","Work_Shift_Required","Public_Job"
"30000","1900-01-01","Chief Executive Officer","","","","","","",
"30100","1900-01-01","Administrator Job Profile","","","","","","",
"30200","1900-01-01","Facilities & Grounds Maintenance Attendant","0","0","Job Description rich text!","Additional Job Description rich text!","0","1",
"30300","1900-01-01","Sample_Job_Title","0","0","Sample Job Description","Sample Additional Job Description","1","",
```

Comment: oh wow... thanks alot! thats it! So looks like there is no need to use the library of CSV? I need to learn what else "set" do. You are amazing!

Comment: you always need to decide if you really need that extra dependency or not, in this case it seems not necessary, though rewriting parts of the CSV gem if you need more functionality would be bad also. If you need more info on a Set see here https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html